# In Twig template, how to access an element like "@attributes" in an object?

Tags: xml, attributes, twig

I am consuming a API and the returned data has one section `rss` and looks like below:

[image]

In my Twig template, I can access **everything** in the `rss` section except `@attributes` in `enclosure` section. For example:

```
    {% set rss=res.rss %}
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        {% for r in rss %}
            {% set e=r.enclosure %}
            {{ dump(e) }}
            <li class="media">
                <img class="d-flex mr-3 img-fluid" width="64" src="" alt="{{ r.title }}">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1"><a href="{{ r.link }}" target="_blank" title="{{ r.pubDate }}">{{ r.title }}</a></h5>
                    {{ r.pubDate|date('Y-m-d') }}
                </div>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

The dumping of `e` (the `enclosure` object) is successful and looks like below:

[image]

The question is how to get that `url` under `enclosure:@attributes`?

Comment: Did you try the array notation, e.g. `e['@attributes']`? If its in the dump i'm sure you can access it like that

Comment: I had made a "go-around" approach. Now I do the process in the Symfony Controller class instead of in Twig template.